# As in truffle tests pass the check by block.timestamp?

Tags: solidity, truffle-test

I have 2 functions

```
    function startBuilding ()
        public
    {
        uint[8] memory _buildingInfo;
        _buildingInfo[1] = uint32(block.timestamp) + 2 minutes;
        addBuilding(_buildingInfo);
    }


    function finishBuilding ()
        public
    {
        uint[8] memory _buildingInfo;
        require (buildingInfo[1] <= block.timestamp);

        buildingInfo[6] = STATUS_NEW;       
    }
```

Truffle Test

```
    it("Function 'Building' work", async function() {
        await buildingContract.startBuilding();

        // Here you need to rewind time ahead by 2 minutes

        await buildingContract.finishBuilding();
    });
```

How to rewind time ahead by `2 minutes` to get tested `require (buildingInfo [1] <= block.timestamp)` ???

> `sleep()` - will not work, because the test will be done for a very
>   long time, because there are a lot of smart contracts like `require`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Truffle 4.1.15 & Ganache 6.2.5, you can use this:

```
web3.currentProvider.send({method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [120]});
```

Note that:

1. Between Truffle v4 and Truffle v5, Web3 has changed from v0 to v1, so the above might be different on Truffle 5.x (for example, I think you need to `await` for the function to complete).
2. Method `evm_increaseTime` is 1 of 4 non-standard methods that aren’t included within the original RPC specification (i.e., it is proprietary for Ganache, see [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#implemented-methods) for more details).